# Ubuntu 18.04: Nautilus Desktop's folder icon frozen (unclickable)

Tags: nautilus, icons, notification

For every boot, I can't click folders on my desktop, for apps there is no problem. Also, every time I download something from browser and click "show in File Manager", a notification of "Files is ready" pops out (see below), the nautilus does open a new window but doesn't pop out, you have to click the dock icon to open it by yourself.

[image]

The only solution is `killall nautilus-desktop` and then `nautilus-desktop & disown`. However, despite now I can click, there are two problems:

1. Every time I click an icon, nautilus will show a notification, same "File is ready" shown above, and it does pop out.
2. For downloads it pops out as well, with notification.
3. After rebooting, I have to do it again.

I have tried to reinstall nautilus, but the problem persists.